# What are the attributes that make 'types-first' programming in Scala have less code and less bugs?

Tags: scala, types, monads, category-theory

I attended a Scala course called 'Patterns in Types' [based on this repository](https://github.com/markhibberd/yow-patterns-in-types). The course covers the following ideas:

- [Error Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html)
- [Reader Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html)
- [Writer Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html)
- [State Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html)
- [Reader Monad Transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.1.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html)
- [Writer Monad Transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html)
- [State Monad Transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html)
- Relating this all back to [http values in a web server](https://github.com/markhibberd/yow-patterns-in-types/tree/master/src/main/scala/challenge8a)

The background is that the course teachers were very keen on [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz).

The reasoning behind this design approach was that programming [*types-first*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255355/is-design-with-types-first-ultimately-the-same-as-design-with-interfaces-firs) ***leads to less code and less bugs***. I'm trying to wrap my head around this reasoning.

My question is: **What are the attributes that make 'types-first' programming in Scala have less code and less bugs?**

Comment: I don't have anything to say about Scala, I only saw this because you tagged it "haskell". That said, here are some links on the topic:


http://bitemyapp.com/posts/2014-11-18-strong-types-and-testing.html


http://bitemyapp.com/posts/2014-12-03-why-are-types-useful.html


http://bitemyapp.com/posts/2014-11-19-update-map-in-haskell.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that less bugs are expected because you give the complier as much information as possible and therefore it can find issues already during compilation. Otherwise they would occur at runtime.

Regarding less code I am not sure, but maybe the idea is that Scalaz does a lot of magic for you so you don't have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Rado - could you give an example of a bug that this would address?

Comment: I thought I knew, but then I thought again and I am not sure ... my idea was for example never to use simple types like String, but to represent them by domain types (even though they are just "strings" in memory). That would protect you from making bugs, beause a String can contain anything, but a domain type cannot.